# What's the correct MSDTC configuation for a clustered SQL server for BizTalk WCF SQL adapter

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, biztalk, msdtc

I have a issue on connecting to a clustered sql server instance using wcf-sql adapter.
The sql cluster infrastructure is :

We have 2 servers, SVR1 and SVR2, each have a named SQL instance INST1 installed and these 2 servers are clustered. In SRV1, a clustered MSDTC installed and assigned a NETBIOS name as DTCCLUSTER1. SRV1/SRV2 and DTCCLUSTER1 have its own IP address.

When I try to connect to this SQL Server using WCF-SQL Adapter, I got a timeout error and finally find out this is caused by a MSDTC connection issue. DTCPing test failed in both SRV1 to BizTalk server and BizTalk to SRV1.

The SRV1 hosting DTCCLUSTER1 have been configured to allow both inbound and outbound connections. For security reason, we cannot allow "No Auth" in MSDTC but choosed "Mutual Auth required" in both SRV1 and BizTalk server side.

On server side, the firewall was configured to allow DCE RPC inbound and outbound. We even disabled the firewall in BizTalk server side. Also no port blocking by network.

We are still doing the troubleshooting now, but my question here is kind of more general: what's the proper configuration of the MSDTC for a clustered SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there MIGHT be a workaround by setting the UseAmbientTransaction property to false.

Off course, the MSDTC issue is your main concern :)

Are you sure you checked the Network DTC access checkbox as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897483(v=bts.10).aspx

For more information on troubleshooting these specific issues, please see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924(v=bts.10).aspx
This link provides you with some good advice on how to set these properties.

More specifically, if you enable the mutual auth required option, take a look at this paragraph:

> If either the Mutual Authentication Required or the Incoming Caller
>   Authentication Required configuration options are enabled then the
>   client(s) computer account must be granted the Access this computer
>   from the network user right. If the computer account for a client
>   computer is not granted the Access this computer from the network user
>   right, or is included in the Deny access to this computer from the
>   network user right, then DTC communication between the client and
>   server computer will fail.

Typically I always set no auth. It might be worth it to try the setting and see if this makes it work. Also be aware that MSDTC settings need to be the same across your BizTalk and SQL servers, including your MSDTC cluster (IIRC: if you have a windows 2008 R2 msdtc cluster).